# Alerting QDataWidgetMapper to changes when using a custom Model & Delegate

Tags: python, pyqt, qabstracttablemodel, qdatawidgetmapper

I'm using a subclassed *QAbstractTableModel* with *dataclasses* as items. Each *dataclass* contains a field "field1" with a **list**, which I'd like to display in a listview and have it automatically change whenever I edit or add an item in the listview.

To do that I set a custom delegate to the *QDataWidgetMapper* which will retrieve and set the values from that *dataclass*. This works the way I want it to.

My problem is that I want to add additional items to that listview with the press of a button and have the *QDataWidgetMapper* add them automatically to the model.

This is what I have so far:

[image: ListView with three items and a QPushButton underneath]

```
import sys
import dataclasses
from typing import List, Any
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *


@dataclasses.dataclass()
class StorageItem:

    field1: List[str] = dataclasses.field(default_factory=list)


class StorageModel(QAbstractTableModel):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        test = StorageItem()
        test.field1 = ['Item °1', 'Item °2']
        self._data: List[StorageItem] = [test]

    def data(self, index: QModelIndex, role: int = ...) -> Any:
        if not index.isValid():
            return

        item = self._data[index.row()]
        col = index.column()

        if role in {Qt.DisplayRole, Qt.EditRole}:
            if col == 0:
                return item.field1
            else:
                return None

    def setData(self, index: QModelIndex, value, role: int = ...) -> bool:

        if not index.isValid() or role != Qt.EditRole:
            return False

        item = self._data[index.row()]
        col = index.column()

        if col == 0:
            item.field1 = value

        self.dataChanged.emit(index, index)
        print(self._data)
        return True

    def flags(self, index: QModelIndex) -> Qt.ItemFlags:
        return Qt.ItemFlags(
            Qt.ItemIsEnabled | Qt.ItemIsSelectable | Qt.ItemIsEditable
        )

    def rowCount(self, parent=None) -> int:
        return len(self._data)

    def columnCount(self, parent=None) -> int:
        return len(dataclasses.fields(StorageItem))


class TestDelegate(QStyledItemDelegate):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

    def setEditorData(self, editor: QWidget, index: QModelIndex) -> None:
        if isinstance(editor, QListView):
            data = index.model().data(index, Qt.DisplayRole)
            editor.model().setStringList(data)
        else:
            super().setEditorData(editor, index)

    def setModelData(
            self, editor: QWidget,
            model: QAbstractItemModel,
            index: QModelIndex
    ) -> None:

        if isinstance(editor, QListView):
            data = editor.model().stringList()
            model.setData(index, data, Qt.EditRole)
        else:
            super().setModelData(editor, model, index)


class CustomListView(QListView):

    item_added = pyqtSignal(name='itemAdded')

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.setModel(QStringListModel())

    def add_item(self, item: str):
        str_list = self.model().stringList()
        str_list.append(item)
        self.model().setStringList(str_list)
        self.item_added.emit()


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        cent_widget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(cent_widget)

        # Vertical Layout
        v_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        v_layout.setContentsMargins(10, 10, 10, 10)

        # Listview
        self.listview = CustomListView()
        v_layout.addWidget(self.listview)

        # Button
        self.btn = QPushButton('Add')
        self.btn.clicked.connect(lambda: self.listview.add_item('New Item'))
        v_layout.addWidget(self.btn)

        cent_widget.setLayout(v_layout)

        # Set Mapping
        self.mapper = QDataWidgetMapper()
        self.mapper.setItemDelegate(TestDelegate())
        self.mapper.setSubmitPolicy(QDataWidgetMapper.AutoSubmit)
        self.mapper.setModel(StorageModel())
        self.mapper.addMapping(self.listview, 0)
        self.mapper.toFirst()

        self.listview.itemAdded.connect(self.mapper.submit)


def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    app.exec()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Currently, I'm using the signal **itemAdded** from inside the custom *ListView* to manually submit the *QDataWidgetMapper*.

Is there a way to do this within *CustomListView*, without using a custom signal?
Somehow the delegate knows when data in the listview has been edited. How can I trigger that same mechanism when new items are added?

Comment: I don't understand, you're using two different models here, your subclass and the string list. Besides that, it is **not** responsibility of QDataWidgetMapper to "add items".

Comment: I don't insist on using the *QStringListModel*, I just want to display the contents of "field1" in a QListView and be able to add items to the list in "field1" by pressing the button and have that change reflected in the listview.

Comment: @SirTeddytheFirst From what you understand you have a table type model where an item (in your case 0,0) has a list object as data and then you want to create that the editor associated with a QListView similar to that if the data were a text then the editor would be a QLineEdit. I am right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TL; DR;** It can not.

---

The submitPolicy `QDataWidgetMapper::AutoSubmit` indicates that the model will be updated when focus is lost. The model is also updated when the commitData or closeEditor signal of the delegate is invoked, which happens by default when some specific keys are pressed.

A better implementation would be to create a signal that is emitted every time a change is made in the QListView model and connect it to submit, not just the method of adding elements. Also it is better to use a custom qproperty.

```py
class CustomListView(QListView):
    items_changed = pyqtSignal(name="itemsChanged")

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.setModel(QStringListModel())
        self.model().rowsInserted.connect(self.items_changed)
        self.model().rowsRemoved.connect(self.items_changed)
        self.model().dataChanged.connect(self.items_changed)
        self.model().layoutChanged.connect(self.items_changed)

    def add_item(self, item: str):
        self.items += [item]

    @pyqtProperty(list, notify=items_changed)
    def items(self):
        return self.model().stringList()

    @items.setter
    def items(self, data):
        if len(data) == len(self.items) and all(
            x == y for x, y in zip(data, self.items)
        ):
            return
        self.model().setStringList(data)
        self.items_changed.emit()
```

```py
# Set Mapping
self.mapper = QDataWidgetMapper()
self.mapper.setModel(StorageModel())
self.mapper.addMapping(self.listview, 0, b"items")
self.mapper.toFirst()

self.listview.items_changed.connect(self.mapper.submit)
```

Comment: This is an improvement (thanks for that), but my actual problem is that the model (*StorageModel*) should be updated when *add_item* is called, which currently it is only after I edit an item in the listview after clicking the button.

Comment: @SirTeddytheFirst Unfortunately you cannot. The justification is in my post.